# Apache storm supervisor stops automatically when it run a topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

The three hosts have the same configuration part of /etc/hosts.

```
203.xx.xx.253 server0
203.xx.xx.254 server1
203.xx.xx.255 server2
```

#### zoo.cfg

```
dataDir=/home/xxx/zookeeper/data/`
server.0=server0:2888:3888
server.1=server1:2888:3888
server.2=server2:2888:3888
```

#### storm.yaml

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "server0"
     - "server1"
     - "server2"

nimbus.seeds: ["server0"]

storm.local.dir: "/home/xxx/storm/data"
```

#### test step

1. Run the zookeeper server on those three hosts. Test zookeeper status. That is ok.
2. Run storm nimbus on the host(server0). Run storm ui on the host(server0)
3. Run storm supervisor on the hosts(server0, server1, server2)
4. Verify storm status in the ui page. It is ok.
5. Submit a topology, succeed
6. After abount 1 minutes supervisor died, there is a superviser alive(server0).

#### supervisor.log

```
2018-11-20 04:44:17.346 o.a.s.u.NimbusClient Async Localizer [WARN] Using deprecated config nimbus.host for backward compatibility. Please update your storm.yaml so it only has config nimbus.seeds
2018-11-20 04:44:17.416 o.a.s.u.NimbusClient Async Localizer [INFO] Found leader nimbus : ubuntu:6627
...
2018-11-20 04:44:27.551 o.a.s.u.NimbusClient Async Localizer [WARN] Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from server0. will retry with a different seed host.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ubuntu
...
2018-11-20 08:06:29.129 o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer Async Localizer [WARN] Failed to download basic resources for topology-id hello02-1-1542719091
2018-11-20 08:06:29.129 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps Async Localizer [INFO] Deleting path /home/dragonlab/apache-storm-1.1.1/data/supervisor/tmp/bbca1ecb-60c2-4cb7-a98d-7d82ed6aa716
2018-11-20 08:06:29.139 o.a.s.d.s.AdvancedFSOps Async Localizer [INFO] Deleting path /home/dragonlab/apache-storm-1.1.1/data/supervisor/stormdist/hello02-1-1542719091
2018-11-20 08:06:29.139 o.a.s.l.AsyncLocalizer Async Localizer [WARN] Caught Exception While Downloading (rethrowing)... 
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [server0]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:111) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:57) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore.prepare(NimbusBlobStore.java:268) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getClientBlobStoreForSupervisor(Utils.java:538) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.downloadBaseBlobs(AsyncLocalizer.java:121) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:148) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.AsyncLocalizer$DownloadBaseBlobsDistributed.call(AsyncLocalizer.java:101) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_191]
2018-11-20 08:06:29.140 o.a.s.d.s.Slot SLOT_6705 [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [server0]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.storm.localizer.LocalDownloadedResource$NoCancelFuture.get(LocalDownloadedResource.java:63) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.handleWaitingForBasicLocalization(Slot.java:413) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.stateMachineStep(Slot.java:273) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor.Slot.run(Slot.java:741) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
Caused by: org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [server0]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
...
2018-11-20 08:06:29.140 o.a.s.d.s.Slot SLOT_6704 [ERROR] Error when processing event
...
2018-11-20 08:06:29.142 o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor Thread-5 [INFO] Shutting down supervisor 3646a850-ce83-470c-a6c9-d69257780241
2018-11-20 08:06:29.143 o.a.s.e.EventManagerImp Thread-4 [INFO] Event manager interrupted
```

Every test time I have cleared zookeeper data and storm temporary data.

```
rmr /storm
```

How can I resolve follow error message : "Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts server0. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?"

Ping to 'server0' is OK. Why supervisors cant find 'server0'.

thanks

Comment: Where is this cropping up? ` Found leader nimbus : ubuntu:6627 ...` . Is there any other host config?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. Both machines have the same hostname. The contents of my /etc/ file are as follows：127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
203.xxx.xxx.253 server0
203.xxx.xxx.223 server1
203.xxx.xxx.226 server2.    Removed "ubuntu" and solved it